# Flutter circular animation on event

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I am trying to implement such animation using AnimatedPositioned widget, where it will move around center point clockwise or counterclockwise by a certain degree on event. Basically like planet around the sun.
I am using this function to calculate movement:

```
  double x = 0;
  double y = 0;
  double radius;
  void updatePosition({
    @required double centerX,
    @required double centerY,
  }) {
    radius = min(centerX, centerY);
    x = centerX + radius * cos(angle * -pi / 90);
    y = centerX + radius * sin(angle * -pi / 90);
    angle += 5;
  }
```

But i cannot wrap my head around how to adjust initial points in relation to the center of container with given constrains.

Comment: i think in this case, you need to use `Transform`, in my case, if animation get complex, i use `rive`

Comment: You mean Transform.rotate ? I t's not such a complex animation to use rive, just a simple widget orbiting around given point.